# ESP8266 via ArduinoIDE on Mac OSX issue

Tags: arduino, osx-elcapitan, esp8266

I have recently switch to Macbook and got some troubles with ESP8266 programming via ArduinoIDE. As far as I know my USB-TTL converter is basen on PL2303 series. I have already tried this solution:
http://hpclab.blogspot.com/2015/06/esp8266-arduino-ide-on-mac-os-x.html
But I have just downloaded files and went with `sudo python setup.py install` so I got my files in `/usr/local/bin`. Then I changed the platform.txt as written at blog and as result I got:
http://pastebin.com/up7ec8q4
I would be really glad if anyone of you could help me with that.
Best regards.

Comment: So what is the issue then? Please show the appropriate information here.

Comment: Well with changed esptool -> esptool.py I can upload program but esp restarts on every Serial.read() command, when I switch to Win7 works just fine. I don't know how to change esptool in newer version of arduino-esp8266 2.0.0 so can't check if it would work but I truly doubt that.